# Why does my select statement on a filtered view return 0 records although user has CRM permissions?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a Dynamics CRM 2011 on-premise installation and I want to retrieve records from the FilteredAccount view. I do this in the context of a domain user that is also an enabled CRM user with CRM read permissions.

Previously, this has worked fine, but suddenly this has stopped working, i.e. the query now yields 0 records. 
The same query executed in the context of the CRM deployment administrator user I can query the view just fine and I can also see that the user (for which the select statement returns 0 records) is present in the FilteredSystemUser view with access mode == read.
That user is also a member in the correct ActiveDirectory CRM Reporting Group.

From what I can see, this user should have all the necessary permissions. What else could have an impact on the records returned from the query?

Comment: Is this a fresh deployment? I've sometimes seen issues on the actual security roles of the filtered view itself in Sql Server when multiple organisations have been deployed. Also an arbitrary question but has to be asked, it did work now it doesn't. So I usually ask, what's changed that would have caused it to break?

Comment: Maybe I should have explicitely stated that, but I cannot think of anything that could have broken the user permissions.

Comment: Does the user hold the necessary privileges in CRM, beside being a user? Does an Advanced Find return results for the user?

Comment: An advanced find does indeed find this user. The user profile states that Access Mode is read and License Type is Limited. As I am just starting to get familiar with Dynamics, are there other places where more and possibly finer-grained permissions for users are managed? Also, this is a relatively fresh deployment, maybe 2 weeks old. As of now, the purpose of the deployment is to get a proof-of-concept working on how to integrate Dynamics content into Sharepoint Enterprise Search. So in essence, all that was done was to create some dummy data and query it with SELECTs.

Comment: @Hatch what ckeller meant was , not an advanced find to find the user. But to log in to crm as that particular user, and execute an advanced find that mimics the query you wish to run on the filtered views. If that doesn't return data, then there is a problem with the CRM permissions ( not AD permissions )

Comment: I do not have enough reputation points to answer my own question, so unfortunately I have to post this comment and will update later: It turns out that the user in question did not have a security role assigned. Re-assigning the correct security role fixed the problem. I am however clueless as to what could have caused this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the user in question did not have a security role assigned. Re-assigning the correct security role fixed the problem. I am however clueless as to what could have caused this.

Comment: Did you move the user to another business unit? In this case all roles are removed for this user.

Answer (score 2):

For my situation, the CRM user's domainname was somehow changed, like mydomain\user_1 to mydomain\user1.

Resolution is to go to crm database, find systemuser view, change the domainname column value to one supposed to be.